# Limits - Simplifying an expression

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

How would you simplify this expression, in order to solve the limit:

(1)$$ \lim_{\substack{z\rightarrow 0\\}} \frac {e^{iz} - e^{-iz}} {i(e^z-e^{-z})} $$

I got here from the following limit:

$$ \lim_{\substack{z\rightarrow 0\\}} \frac {sin z}{sh (iz)} $$

I substituted the $sin$ z and $sh (iz)$, and then got expression in (1).

Comment: Check your limit that you've obtained to see if it's correct.  That looks more like $\frac{\sin(z)}{\sinh(z)}$ than $\frac{\sin(z)}{\sinh(iz)}$.

Comment: @Donkey_2009 Oh.. you're correct. I totally forgot $i$. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want it simplified for? Apply l'Hospital's rule!

$$\lim_{z\to 0}\frac {e^{iz} - e^{-iz}} {i(e^z-e^{-z})}\stackrel{\text{l'Hospital}}=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{e^z+e^{-z}}=1$$

Comment: Thank you. Forgot about l'hospital. Damn me! I can't upvote you tho, not enough reputation.

Comment: I'll be able to accept the answer in 1 minute. In order to upvote, it seems I need 15reputation.

Comment: @Don Antonio: Is the l'Hospial rule applied to complex-valued functions? Could you give a reference?

Comment: McMahon's "Complex Variables Demystified", page 50, 3.12, Agarwal-Perera-Pinelas's "An Introduction to Complex Analysis", page 38 Theorem 6.3 , etc. But you can try to prove it by yourself: it's practically the same as with real variables (for the case $\;\frac00\;$ !)

Comment: Ah. somebody didn't like my answer...oh, well.

Comment: @ Don Antonio: Thank you. But theorem 3.2 is not proved there, only claimed. Up to [the problem book](http://lib.org.by/info/M_Mathematics/MC_Calculus/MCc_Complex%20variable/Evgrafov%20M.A.%20(red.)%20Sbornik%20zadach%20po%20teorii%20analiticheskix%20funkcij%20(2e%20izd.,%201972)(ru)(K)(600dpi)(T)(416s).djvu), the l'Hospital rule for complex-valued function is only valid under certain additional conditions comparatively with real-valued functions . Unfortunately, as far as I know it, that book has not been translated into English

Comment: The rule is valid under the usual condition of analycity and existence of the limit of $\;f'/g'\;$., and the proof appears in the book of Agarwal and et. It never minds, though: follow the general proof of the real case!